# Is there a way to increase write speed to file for this script

Tags: powershell

is there a way to speed up and optimize this .ps1 script. It writes to file at around 1KB/s which is kind of slow if files are bigger than few MB.

This script reads file by line and increments each occurence of \<x but each line number resets.

It's my first script so that's why its so barbaric.

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("file")
try {
for() {
    $line = $reader.ReadLine()
    if ($line -eq $null) { break }

    $numbers =  [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($line, "\&lt;x")

    for ($i = $numbers.Count - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--)
    {

        Write-Host ($numbers[$i].Index + $numbers[$i].Length)
        $line = $line.Substring(0, $numbers[$i].Index) +  "\&lt;x" + ($i + 1).ToString() +  $line.Substring($numbers[$i].Index + $numbers[$i].Length)
    } 

    $line | Out-File "outfile" -Append
}   
}
finally {
$reader.Close() 
}
```

Comment: Maybe its due to encoding as it writes as UCS-2 LE BOM and it takes 2x space then normal UTF-8 file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is the file? It might be better to load it to the RAM completely.

```
$lines = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines("file")
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $lines.Count; $i++) { 
    $numbers = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($lines[$i], "\&lt;x")
    for ($n = $numbers.Count - 1; $n -ge 0; $n--) {
        Write-Host ($numbers[$n].Index + $numbers[$n].Length)
        $lines[$i] = $lines[$i].Substring(0, $numbers[$n].Index) +  "\&lt;x" + ($n + 1).ToString() +  $lines[$i].Substring($numbers[$n].Index + $numbers[$n].Length)
    }
}
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines("outfile", $lines)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Your solution is super fast, but i think there is a typo because it does not increment x as it should. Daily files are up to 100mb  but there might be 1 gb in the future.

Comment: Yep. Should be $lines[$i] on the third line. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `Out-File` re-opening and writing to the file every time, you could use a `StreamWriter`:

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("file")

# Create writer to output file
$writer = [System.IO.File]::CreateText("outfile")
try {
    while(-not $reader.EndOfStream) {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()

        $numbers =  [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($line, "\&lt;x")

        for ($i = $numbers.Count - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--)
        {
            Write-Host ($numbers[$i].Index + $numbers[$i].Length)
            $line = $line.Substring(0, $numbers[$i].Index) +  "\&lt;x" + ($i + 1).ToString() +  $line.Substring($numbers[$i].Index + $numbers[$i].Length)
        } 

        # Write line to output file
        $writer.WriteLine($line)
    }
}
catch{}
finally {
    $reader.Close() 
    $writer.Close()
}
```